# Need help on simple circuit with Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

I'm new on Circuitikz. So, I need some help on drawing a little circuit on my electronics report.
The schematic are shown below:
[image: Schematic]

The type of transistor used are nfet. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome top TeX.SE! What you try so far? Do you look in the `circuitikz` package documentation?. There are some useful examples how to draw electric schemes.

Comment: Try http://www.tikzedt.org/

Comment: @FábioGregório  please have alook at the answer below if it satisfies the requirement

Comment: @sandu Unfortunately, it is no more maintained.

Comment: @FábioGregório please have a look at the answer below if it satisfies the requirement

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[nigfetebulk](T1){} ;
    (T1.G) node[anchor=east] {G}
    (T1.D) node[anchor=north] {D}
    (T1.S) node[anchor=south] {S}
    (T1.center) node[anchor=east]{C};
    \draw (0,-2)    node[sground]{} 
            to      (T1.S)coordinate(aux);
    \draw (-2,-2)   node[sground]{}
            to      [V,  invert,]coordinate(vg)
                    node[right=8pt of vg ](v2){$V_2$}
                    node[below right=18pt and 10pt of vg]{${V_gs}$}     (-2,-1)
                    |-      (T1.G)  ;
    \draw (-4,0)    node[sground]{}
            to      [V,  invert]coordinate(vd)
                    node[right=12pt of vd ](v1){$V_1$}
                    node[below right=12pt and 12pt of vd]{${1.2}$}          (-4,1)
            to      [short]++(0,1) 
                    -|      (T1.D);
    \draw (T1.center)
                    node[above right, ]{$M1$}
                    node[below right] {$NMOS$} --++(2,0)
                    |-(aux)
            to      [short,-*](aux) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 from me (but you should have `$v_{gs}$` not `$v_gs$` :-))). BTW, you do not need to add a comment when you post an answer --- the original poster is automatically notified.