# Help for design a circuit on Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I need help to draw this circuit on Circuitikz. The schematic are shown below. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi @Fábio Gregório, what have you tried? Can we help you where you got stuck? It seems that you are using this site as a "please do it for me" site, which is not: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593675/38080, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595126/38080, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600954/38080 (and you do not always accept your answers...). Reading the first couple of tutorials in the `circuitikz` manual will get you started!

Answer (score 4):

This small piece of code should help you get started:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american] 
    \draw (0,0) node[sground]{} to[I, l=$I_1$] ++(0,3)
        to [short, -*] ++(2,0) coordinate(dot1)
        to [C, l2=$C_{ox1}$ and \SI{0.097}{\pico\farad}] ++(0,-3)
        node [sground]{};
    \draw (dot1) to[L=$L_s$, a=\SI{5.18}{\nano\henry}] ++(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you have all the "instruments" here: how to use stacked labels in two different way, the signal ground, the usage of coordinates to stop and restart you drawing, and the syntax for poles.

From here drawing your circuit is a matter of reading the manual and finding the name of the shapes and components. Try it, and if you get stuck, feel free to ask a specific question!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help! ;)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
    \centering
          
        \node[sground] (ground1) at (0, 0) {};
        \node[sground] (ground2) at (4, 3) {};
        
        % Left hand side
        \draw (ground1) to[short, *-] ($(ground1) + (-1, 0)$) to[R, l2= $R_{sub1}$ and 131Meg] ($(ground1) + (-1, 2)$);
        \draw (ground1) -- ($(ground1) + (1, 0)$) to[C, l2_= $C_{sub1}$ and 0.002p] ($(ground1) + (1, 2)$) -- ($(ground1) + (-1, 2)$);
        \draw ($(ground1) + (0, 2)$) to[C, l2= $C_{ox}$ and 0.097p, *-] ($(ground1) + (0, 4)$);
        
        \draw (-4,2) node[sground]{} to[I, l2=$I_1$ and AC 1] ++(0,2) to [short, -*] ++(4,0); 
        
        % Right hand side
        \draw (ground2) to[short, -] ($(ground2) + (0, 0)$) to ($(ground2) + (0, 1)$);
        
        % Horizontal components
    \draw ($(ground1) + (-1, 4)$) to[short, -] ($(ground1) + (0, 4)$) to[american inductor, L=$L_s$, a= 5.18n] ($(ground1) + (2, 4)$) to[R=$R_s$, a= 4.82] ($(ground2) + (0, 1)$);
        \draw ($(ground1) + (0, 4)$) to[short, *-] ($(ground1) + (0, 6)$);
        \draw ($(ground2) + (0, 1)$) to[short, *-] ($(ground2) + (0, 3)$);
        \draw ($(ground1) + (0, 6)$) to[C=$C_p$, a= 0.03p] ($(ground2) + (0, 3)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]